Does the van Stockum dust have closed timelike geodesics?
We work under this explicit form of the metric:
$$ds^2 = -dt^2 - 2br^2\,dtd\phi + (1-b^2r^2)r^2\,d\phi^2 + e^{-b^2r^2}(dz^2 + dr^2).$$
Since the metric coefficients only depend on $r$, we can naturally obtain three Killing vectors corresponding to the energy $E$, $z$-momentum $P_z$, and angular momentum in $\phi$ direction $L$. Moreover, the curve obtained by fixing $r,z,t$ and varying $\phi$ can be made timelike since $\phi$ is periodic.
My question is, although we certainly have a closed timelike curve, is this curve a geodesic? It seems to me that it is, since I don't see how the three conserved quantities would change on the curve. However, on the Wikipedia page for the van Stockum dust, it was remarked (under the section "A genuine paradox") that

These closed timelike curves are not timelike geodesics, so these paradoxical observers must accelerate to experience these effects.

I wonder how one can see that the CTC is not a geodesic?

A subtle theorem tells us that a curve with constant length tangent and having three conserved Killing constants of motion (as you mention) is not necessarily a geodesic! One also needs that the tangent does not fall in the span of the Killing fields. The curve in question certainly does.
Thus I think this is equally as mysterious as asking why curves that move only through Killing time in Schwarzschild aren't geodesic.
To convince yourself of your question, I would recommend simply going through the grunt work and computing the covariant derivative of the tangent of the relevant CTC. (I recommend computing Christoffel symbols -  in fact this just gives you the straight up covariant derivative aforementioned - via finding the stationary points of the energy functional:
$$E[\gamma] := \int g(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma}) d\lambda$$

I see, thanks for your answer! I will try to work out the computations and verify that this curve is not a geodesic.
One other thing - do you happen to have a reference for the theorem that you have mentioned?
